Image Position Misplaced with the Custom controls after Dragging (interact.js integrating)
I have these script that integrate dragging with interact.js but after integrating i cannot get the position of the image right after dragging using interact.js.
Here is the screen recording gif of the problem:
Error Screen Recording
Explanation on the error:

When i skew on the first time (without dragging it first), the image seems to be in normal behaviour (not getting misplaced)
When i dragging the image and then use the controls back again the image getting misplaced getting outside the red dot controls.

Here's my custom controls code:
    // Function to update red dots
            function updateRedDots(offsetX, offsetY) {
                $(controls[0]).css({ left: offsetX + xOffset, top: offsetY + yOffset }).show();
                $(controls[1]).css({ left: offsetX + xOffset + imagePosition.width - $(controls[1]).width(), top: offsetY + yOffset }).show();
                $(controls[2]).css({ left: offsetX + xOffset + imagePosition.width - $(controls[2]).width(), top: offsetY + yOffset + imagePosition.height - $(controls[2]).height() }).show();
                $(controls[3]).css({ left: offsetX + xOffset, top: offsetY + yOffset + imagePosition.height - $(controls[3]).height() }).show();
            }

I want the image keep attached everytime dragging the image and use the custom controls (skew features).
And here's my script:
<script>
        var controls = [];
        var canvas;
        var context;
        var image = new Image();
        var triangles = [];
        var dirtyTriangles = true;
        var opacitySlider = document.getElementById('opacityRange');
        var currentOpacity = 1.0;
        var isDragging = false;
        let imagePosition = { width: 0, height: 0 };
        var interactInstance;
        
        $(document).ready(function() {
            canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
            context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        
            var container = $('#container');
            var containerWidth = container.width();
            var containerHeight = container.height();
        
            canvas.width = containerWidth;
            canvas.height = containerHeight;
            
            // Initialize red dots and blue lines
            for (var i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
                var control = document.createElement('div');
                control.id = 'node' + i;
                $(control).addClass('node').hide();  // Hide red dots initially
                $('#container').append(control);
                controls.push(control);
            }
            
            // Initialize blue lines
            var lines = ['line1', 'line2', 'line3', 'line4'];
            lines.forEach(function(line) {
                var lineElement = document.createElement('div');
                lineElement.id = line;
                $(lineElement).addClass('blue-line').hide();  // Hide blue lines initially
                $('#container').append(lineElement);
            });
        
            for (var i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
                var control = document.createElement('div');
                $(control).addClass('node');
                $('#container').append(control);
                controls.push(control);
            }
            
            // Function to update red dots
            function updateRedDots(offsetX, offsetY) {
                $(controls[0]).css({ left: offsetX + xOffset, top: offsetY + yOffset }).show();
                $(controls[1]).css({ left: offsetX + xOffset + imagePosition.width - $(controls[1]).width(), top: offsetY + yOffset }).show();
                $(controls[2]).css({ left: offsetX + xOffset + imagePosition.width - $(controls[2]).width(), top: offsetY + yOffset + imagePosition.height - $(controls[2]).height() }).show();
                $(controls[3]).css({ left: offsetX + xOffset, top: offsetY + yOffset + imagePosition.height - $(controls[3]).height() }).show();
            }
            
            $('#imageUpload').on('change', function(event) {
                var file = event.target.files[0];
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function(e) {
                    image.src = e.target.result;
                    image.onload = function() {
                        imagePosition.width = 120;
                        imagePosition.height = image.height * (120 / image.width);
            
                        xOffset = (canvas.width - imagePosition.width) / 2;
                        yOffset = (canvas.height - imagePosition.height) / 2;
            
                        // Clear canvas and redraw the image
                        context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                        context.drawImage(image, xOffset, yOffset, imagePosition.width, imagePosition.height);
            
                        // Update red dots positions initially
                        updateRedDots(0, 0);
            
                        $('.opacity-slider').show(); // Show opacity slider
                        $('#downloadButton').show(); // Show download button
            
                        setInterval(draw, 500 / 30);
            
                        // Initialize interact.js instance for the canvas
                        if (interactInstance) {
                            interactInstance.unset();
                        }
            
                        interactInstance = interact('#canvas')
                            .draggable({
                                listeners: {
                                    start() {
                                        isDragging = true;
                                    },
                                    move(event) {
                                        if (isDragging) {
                                            const x = (parseFloat(canvas.getAttribute('data-x')) || 0) + event.dx;
                                            const y = (parseFloat(canvas.getAttribute('data-y')) || 0) + event.dy;
            
                                            canvas.style.transform = `translate(${x}px, ${y}px)`;
                                            canvas.setAttribute('data-x', x);
                                            canvas.setAttribute('data-y', y);
            
                                            // Update red dots' positions
                                            updateRedDots(x, y);
                                        }
                                    },
                                    end() {
                                        isDragging = false;
                                    }
                                }
                            })
                            .resizable({
                                edges: { left: true, right: true, bottom: true, top: true },
                                listeners: {
                                    start() {
                                        isDragging = true;
                                    },
                                    move(event) {
                                        if (isDragging) {
                                            const x = parseFloat(canvas.getAttribute('data-x')) || 0;
                                            const y = parseFloat(canvas.getAttribute('data-y')) || 0;
            
                                            imagePosition.width = event.rect.width;
                                            imagePosition.height = event.rect.height;
            
                                            const newX = x + event.deltaRect.left;
                                            const newY = y + event.deltaRect.top;
            
                                            canvas.style.transform = `translate(${newX}px, ${newY}px)`;
                                            canvas.setAttribute('data-x', newX);
                                            canvas.setAttribute('data-y', newY);
            
                                            // Clear canvas and redraw the image
                                            context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                                            context.drawImage(image, xOffset, yOffset, imagePosition.width, imagePosition.height);
            
                                            // Update red dots' positions
                                            updateRedDots(newX, newY);
                                        }
                                    },
                                    end() {
                                        isDragging = false;
                                    }
                                }
                            });
            
                        // Update red dots' positions
                        updateRedDots(0, 0);
                    };
                };
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            });
            
            /*function draw() {
                context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                var xOffset = (canvas.width - imagePosition.width) / 2;
                var yOffset = (canvas.height - imagePosition.height) / 2;
                context.drawImage(image, xOffset, yOffset, imagePosition.width, imagePosition.height);
                updateRedDots(xOffset, yOffset);
            }*/
            
            $('#dragButton').on('click', function() {
                enableDragMode();
            });
            
            $('#skewButton').on('click', function() {
                enableSkewMode();
            });
            
            function enableDragMode() {
                disableSkewMode();
                $('#dragButton').addClass('active');
                interactInstance = interact('#container')
                    .draggable({
                        listeners: {
                            move(event) {
                                const target = event.target;
                                const x = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-x')) || 0) + event.dx;
                                const y = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-y')) || 0) + event.dy;
            
                                target.style.transform = `translate(${x}px, ${y}px)`;
                                target.setAttribute('data-x', x);
                                target.setAttribute('data-y', y);
                            }
                        }
                    });
            }
            
            function enableSkewMode() {
                disableDragMode();
                $('#skewButton').addClass('active');
                interactInstance = interact('#container')
                    .resizable({
                        edges: { left: true, right: true, bottom: true, top: true },
                        listeners: {
                            move(event) {
                                const target = event.target;
                                let x = parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-x')) || 0;
                                let y = parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-y')) || 0;
            
                                target.style.width = `${event.rect.width}px`;
                                target.style.height = `${event.rect.height}px`;
            
                                x += event.deltaRect.left;
                                y += event.deltaRect.top;
            
                                target.style.transform = `translate(${x}px, ${y}px)`;
                                target.setAttribute('data-x', x);
                                target.setAttribute('data-y', y);
                            }
                        }
                    });
            }
            
            function disableDragMode() {
                $('#dragButton').removeClass('active');
                if (interactInstance) {
                    interactInstance.unset();
                }
            }
            
            function disableSkewMode() {
                $('#skewButton').removeClass('active');
                if (interactInstance) {
                    interactInstance.unset();
                }
            }
        
            // Function to handle the dragging of nodes
            function handleDrag(node, offsetX, offsetY) {
                $(document).on('mousemove touchmove', function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault(); // Prevent default scrolling behavior on touch devices
                    e.stopPropagation(); // Prevent event from propagating to parent elements
            
                    var x = (e.pageX || e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX) - $('#container').offset().left - offsetX;
                    var y = (e.pageY || e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY) - $('#container').offset().top - offsetY;
            
                    // Update node position
                    $(node).css({
                        'left': x + 'px',
                        'top': y + 'px'
                    });
            
                    dirtyTriangles = true;
                    drawLines();
                });
            
                $(document).on('mouseup touchend', function() {
                    $(document).off('mousemove touchmove');
                    $(document).off('mouseup touchend');
                });
            }
            
            // Mouse down event
            $('body').on('mousedown touchstart', function(e) {
                if ($(e.target).hasClass('node')) {
                    var node = e.target;
                    var offsetX = e.pageX - $(node).offset().left;
                    var offsetY = e.pageY - $(node).offset().top;
                    handleDrag(node, offsetX, offsetY);
                }
            });
            
            // CSS to prevent selection during dragging
            $('body').on('mousedown touchstart', function(e) {
                if ($(e.target).hasClass('node')) {
                    e.preventDefault(); // Prevent text selection and other default behaviors
                }
            });
        
            opacitySlider.addEventListener('input', function() {
                currentOpacity = opacitySlider.value / 100;
                draw();
            });
        
            document.getElementById('downloadButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
                downloadImage();
            });
            
            function drawLines() {
                var controlPositions = [
                    { x: parseInt($(controls[0]).css('left')), y: parseInt($(controls[0]).css('top')) },
                    { x: parseInt($(controls[1]).css('left')), y: parseInt($(controls[1]).css('top')) },
                    { x: parseInt($(controls[2]).css('left')), y: parseInt($(controls[2]).css('top')) },
                    { x: parseInt($(controls[3]).css('left')), y: parseInt($(controls[3]).css('top')) }
                ];
            
                var lineElements = ['line1', 'line2', 'line3', 'line4'];
            
                lineElements.forEach(function(line, index) {
                    var lineElement = document.getElementById(line);
                    var nextIndex = (index + 1) % 4;
                    var startPos = controlPositions[index];
                    var endPos = controlPositions[nextIndex];
            
                    var length = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(endPos.x - startPos.x, 2) + Math.pow(endPos.y - startPos.y, 2));
                    var angle = Math.atan2(endPos.y - startPos.y, endPos.x - startPos.x) * 180 / Math.PI;
            
                    $(lineElement).css({
                        width: length + 'px',
                        transform: 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)',
                        transformOrigin: '0 0',  // Rotate around the start point
                        left: startPos.x + 'px',
                        top: startPos.y + 'px'
                    }).show();
                });
            }
            
            $(document).ready(function() {
                // Toggle instructions visibility
                $('#toggleInstructions').on('click', function() {
                    var instructions = $('#instructions');
                    if (instructions.is(':visible')) {
                        instructions.hide();
                        $(this).text('Lihat Petunjuk');
                    } else {
                        instructions.show();
                        $(this).text('Sembunyikan Petunjuk');
                    }
                });
            });
            
        });
        
        var draw = function() {
            context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        
            var render = function(wireframe, image, tri) {
                if (wireframe) {
                    context.strokeStyle = "black";
                    context.beginPath();
                    context.moveTo(tri.p0.x, tri.p0.y);
                    context.lineTo(tri.p1.x, tri.p1.y);
                    context.lineTo(tri.p2.x, tri.p2.y);
                    context.lineTo(tri.p0.x, tri.p0.y);
                    context.stroke();
                    context.closePath();
                }
        
                if (image) {
                    context.globalAlpha = currentOpacity;
                    drawTriangle(context, image,
                        tri.p0.x, tri.p0.y,
                        tri.p1.x, tri.p1.y,
                        tri.p2.x, tri.p2.y,
                        tri.t0.u, tri.t0.v,
                        tri.t1.u, tri.t1.v,
                        tri.t2.u, tri.t2.v);
                }
            };
        
            if (dirtyTriangles) {
                dirtyTriangles = false;
                calculateGeometry();
            }
        
            for (triangle of triangles) {
                render(false, image, triangle);
            }
        };
        
        var calculateGeometry = function() {
            triangles = [];
        
            var subs = 5;
            var divs = 5;
        
            var p1 = new Point(parseInt($(controls[0]).css('left')), parseInt($(controls[0]).css('top')));
            var p2 = new Point(parseInt($(controls[1]).css('left')), parseInt($(controls[1]).css('top')));
            var p3 = new Point(parseInt($(controls[2]).css('left')), parseInt($(controls[2]).css('top')));
            var p4 = new Point(parseInt($(controls[3]).css('left')), parseInt($(controls[3]).css('top')));
        
            var dx1 = p4.x - p1.x;
            var dy1 = p4.y - p1.y;
            var dx2 = p3.x - p2.x;
            var dy2 = p3.y - p2.y;
        
            var imgW = image.width;
            var imgH = image.height;
        
            for (var sub = 0; sub < subs; ++sub) {
                var curRow = sub / subs;
                var nextRow = (sub + 1) / subs;
        
                var curRowX1 = p1.x + dx1 * curRow;
                var curRowY1 = p1.y + dy1 * curRow;
        
                var curRowX2 = p2.x + dx2 * curRow;
                var curRowY2 = p2.y + dy2 * curRow;
        
                var nextRowX1 = p1.x + dx1 * nextRow;
                var nextRowY1 = p1.y + dy1 * nextRow;
        
                var nextRowX2 = p2.x + dx2 * nextRow;
                var nextRowY2 = p2.y + dy2 * nextRow;
        
                for (var div = 0; div < divs; ++div) {
                    var curCol = div / divs;
                    var nextCol = (div + 1) / divs;
        
                    var dCurX = curRowX2 - curRowX1;
                    var dCurY = curRowY2 - curRowY1;
                    var dNextX = nextRowX2 - nextRowX1;
                    var dNextY = nextRowY2 - nextRowY1;
        
                    var p1x = curRowX1 + dCurX * curCol;
                    var p1y = curRowY1 + dCurY * curCol;
        
                    var p2x = curRowX1 + (curRowX2 - curRowX1) * nextCol;
                    var p2y = curRowY1 + (curRowY2 - curRowY1) * nextCol;
        
                    var p3x = nextRowX1 + dNextX * nextCol;
                    var p3y = nextRowY1 + dNextY * nextCol;
        
                    var p4x = nextRowX1 + dNextX * curCol;
                    var p4y = nextRowY1 + dNextY * curCol;
        
                    var u1 = curCol * imgW;
                    var u2 = nextCol * imgW;
                    var v1 = curRow * imgH;
                    var v2 = nextRow * imgH;
        
                    var triangle1 = new Triangle(
                        new Point(p1x-1, p1y),
                        new Point(p3x+2, p3y+1),
                        new Point(p4x-1, p4y+1),
                        new TextCoord(u1, v1),
                        new TextCoord(u2, v2),
                        new TextCoord(u1, v2)
                    );
                    
                    var triangle2 = new Triangle(
                        new Point(p1x-2, p1y),
                        new Point(p2x+1, p2y),
                        new Point(p3x+1, p3y+1),
                        new TextCoord(u1, v1),
                        new TextCoord(u2, v1),
                        new TextCoord(u2, v2)
                    );
        
                    triangles.push(triangle1);
                    triangles.push(triangle2);
                }
            }
        };
        
        var drawTriangle = function(ctx, im, x0, y0, x1, y1, x2, y2,
            sx0, sy0, sx1, sy1, sx2, sy2) {
            ctx.save();
        
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(x0, y0);
            ctx.lineTo(x1, y1);
            ctx.lineTo(x2, y2);
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.clip();
        
            var denom = sx0 * (sy2 - sy1) - sx1 * sy2 + sx2 * sy1 + (sx1 - sx2) * sy0;
            if (denom == 0) {
                return;
            }
            var m11 = -(sy0 * (x2 - x1) - sy1 * x2 + sy2 * x1 + (sy1 - sy2) * x0) / denom;
            var m12 = (sy1 * y2 + sy0 * (y1 - y2) - sy2 * y1 + (sy2 - sy1) * y0) / denom;
            var m21 = (sx0 * (x2 - x1) - sx1 * x2 + sx2 * x1 + (sx1 - sx2) * x0) / denom;
            var m22 = -(sx1 * y2 + sx0 * (y1 - y2) - sx2 * y1 + (sx2 - sx1) * y0) / denom;
            var dx = (sx0 * (sy2 * x1 - sy1 * x2) + sy0 * (sx1 * x2 - sx2 * x1) + (sx2 * sy1 - sx1 * sy2) * x0) / denom;
            var dy = (sx0 * (sy2 * y1 - sy1 * y2) + sy0 * (sx1 * y2 - sx2 * y1) + (sx2 * sy1 - sx1 * sy2) * y0) / denom;
        
            ctx.transform(m11, m12, m21, m22, dx, dy);
        
            ctx.drawImage(im, 0, 0);
            ctx.restore();
        };
        
        var Point = function(x,y) {
            this.x = x ? x : 0;
            this.y = y ? y : 0;
        }
        
        var TextCoord = function(u,v) {
            this.u = u ? u : 0;
            this.v = v ? v : 0;
        }
        
        var Triangle = function(p0, p1, p2, t0, t1, t2) {
            this.p0 = p0;
            this.p1 = p1;
            this.p2 = p2;
            this.t0 = t0;
            this.t1 = t1;
            this.t2 = t2;
        }
        
        function downloadImage() {
            // Create a new canvas to combine the container background and the canvas image
            var downloadCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            var downloadContext = downloadCanvas.getContext('2d');
            downloadCanvas.width = canvas.width;
            downloadCanvas.height = canvas.height;
        
            // Draw the container background
            var containerBg = new Image();
            containerBg.src = $('#container').css('background-image').replace(/url\(['"]?(.*?)['"]?\)/, '$1');
            containerBg.onload = function() {
                downloadContext.drawImage(containerBg, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        
                // Draw the canvas image
                downloadContext.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0);
        
                // Create a link element
                var link = document.createElement('a');
                link.download = 'mockup_hasil.png';
                link.href = downloadCanvas.toDataURL('image/png');
                link.click();
            };
        }
        
        /*ZOOM FUNCTION1*/
        let zoomFactor = 1; // Initial zoom factor
        let isZoomed = false; // Flag to track zoom state
        let skewX = 0; // Initial skew values
        let skewY = 0;
        
        // Function to handle zoom on mouse wheel
        function zoom(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            const zoomAmount = 0.1; // Amount to zoom each level
        
            if (e.deltaY < 0) {
                zoomFactor += zoomAmount; // Zoom in
            } else {
                zoomFactor -= zoomAmount; // Zoom out
                if (zoomFactor < 1) zoomFactor = 1; // Prevent zooming out too far
            }
        
            updateTransform(e.clientX, e.clientY); // Pass the mouse coordinates to adjust zoom
        }
        
        // Function to update the transform CSS property
        function updateTransform(x, y) {
            const container = document.getElementById('container');
            const containerRect = container.getBoundingClientRect();
            
            // Calculate the position relative to the container
            const offsetX = (x - containerRect.left) / containerRect.width;
            const offsetY = (y - containerRect.top) / containerRect.height;
        
            container.style.transform = `scale(${zoomFactor}) skew(${skewX}deg, ${skewY}deg)`;
            container.style.transformOrigin = `${offsetX * 100}% ${offsetY * 100}%`; // Adjust transform origin based on the click position
        }
        
        // Function to toggle zoom
        function toggleZoom(e) {
            const container = document.getElementById('container');
            
            const rect = container.getBoundingClientRect();
            const x = e.clientX - rect.left; // Get click position relative to container
            const y = e.clientY - rect.top;
        
            if (isZoomed) {
                // Zoom out
                zoomFactor = 1;
                container.classList.remove('zoom-out-cursor');
                container.classList.add('zoom-in-cursor');
            } else {
                // Zoom in
                zoomFactor = 1.5;
                container.classList.remove('zoom-in-cursor');
                container.classList.add('zoom-out-cursor');
            }
            updateTransform(x + rect.left, y + rect.top); // Pass the adjusted coordinates
            isZoomed = !isZoomed; // Toggle zoom state
        }
        
        // Attach event listener to the canvas
        document.getElementById('canvas').addEventListener('click', toggleZoom);
        
        // Function to update skew values
        function updateSkew(newSkewX, newSkewY) {
            skewX = newSkewX;
            skewY = newSkewY;
            updateTransform();
        }
        
        // Attach zoom functionality to the container-wrapper
        document.getElementById('container-wrapper').addEventListener('wheel', zoom);
        
        // Toggle zoom on button click
        document.getElementById('zoom-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
            toggleZoom({ clientX: window.innerWidth / 2, clientY: window.innerHeight / 2 }); // Default to center if no event
        });
        
        // Click outside the container to close zoom
        document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
            if (isZoomed && !event.target.closest('#container-wrapper, #zoom-button')) {
                // Reset zoom
                zoomFactor = 1;
                updateTransform();
                isZoomed = false;
            }
        });
        
        // Ensure the zoom is applied correctly when clicking inside the container-wrapper
        document.getElementById('container-wrapper').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation(); // Prevent the click event from bubbling up to the document
        });
        
        // Example function to update skew and reapply transformations
        function setSkew(x, y) {
            updateSkew(x, y); // Update skew values and adjust transformations
        }
    </script>

I've tried to register the updateRedDots(x, y); to the interact.js dragging. But still no luck.
